# I don't seem to understand the super() Keyword and it's usage quite well

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

I know that you use it when inheriting from another class and that you have to call it first inside of a constructor, also that an empty super() method is automatically called instead if I don't call it manually.

For example, We have a Parent class called bank:

```
public class bank implements Comparable<bank> {
        private String owner;
        public String money;
        public boolean intheCubby;

public bank(String name, String ownersName) {
        owner = ownersName;
        money = name;
    }
```

And a Subclass called Account:

```
public class Account extends bank {

    private int totalquantity;
    public int neededquantity;

    public Account(String name, int n) {
        super(name, name);
        money = name;
        totalquantity = n;

    }

    public Account(String name, int n, String ownersName) {
        super(name,ownersName);
        money = name;
        totalquantity = n;
        setOwner(ownersName);

    }
```

So I understand that it works like this you have the bank constructor in the Parentclass with 2 String arguments.
Your super(); method should, therefore also contain 2 arguments of the type String. 
But what if the constructor of the subclass only has (String, int) arguments should I just put (String, null) into my super(); method? Because I have to insert something else I get an Error.

Comment: null is not a valid value for a primitive type like int

Answer (score 2):

You have to call one of the super class's constructors from the sub class constructor.

If the super class only has a single constructor that accepts two `String`s, you must call that constructor from the sub class constructor. Your sub-class's constructor should decide which `String` instances to pass to the super class constructor.

In your example,

```
public Account(String name, int n, String ownersName) {
    super(name, ownersName);
    ...
}
```

will work.

```
public Account(String name, int n) {
    super(name, "someDefaultValue"); // or super(name, null);
    ...
}
```

will also work.

Comment: So what I understand is that I could call Account(arguments); in another Account constructor?

Comment: @SupEldrix you can, as long as that other constructor calls an existing super class constructor (i.e. calls super(...) with the correct number and type of parameters).

Answer (score 1):

The Bank class only has a constructor with a `name` and `ownersName` parameter. So when calling `super()` from the `Account` class, you'll have to decide how you want to initialize both these parameters. If you do not have an `ownersName` in `Account`, you could indeed pass null as second argument. This could potentially lead to issues though later on if the Bank class really relies on an `ownersName` being set.

I also find it strange that `Account` extends `Bank`, since an Account isn't really a Bank. But I might be missing full context of your design here. If would rather expect bank to be a field of `Account`, or `Bank` to have an `ArrayList<Account>` field.

Comment: I just had to make a quick example it's not a real program I'm working on I just wanted
to recreate my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case chaining the constructors with this(); would've been
optimal.